# Create word/pdf file from php with angular data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to output a `form` in word document.. and the best solution I got with some research is using php header(), i.e.

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=output.doc");
```

I've created simple word file from this method easily,
but in my project, I am getting data from angularjs.. This is my code in Angular Controller..

```
$scope.createdoc = function () {

    $scope.textContent = "hello";

    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "doc.php",
        data: {
            items: $scope.items,
            length: $scope.items.length
        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

    });

    request.success(function (data) {
        $scope.textContent = "Document created successfully "+data;
    });
}
```

and this is my code in `doc.php`

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$array = json_decode($json, true);


header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=output.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
echo "<body>";
echo "<p>This is Document body</p>";
echo "</body>";
```

I have done this before in simple php file which prompted to download a `doc` file with the content `This is Document body` but this time, its displaying all these echo'ed lines in html page where I am printing the $scope.textContent `i.e. {{textContent}}`

like this,

```
Document created successfully <html><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252"><body><p>This is Document body</p></body></html>
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing AngularJS and PHP in parallel...
My code looks like this,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=output.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
echo "<body>";
echo "<p style = \"color: $_POST["color"]; font-size: $_POST["font"].px; font-family: $_POST["family"]\">{$_POST['text']}</p>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
}
?>
```

That is instead of assigning values to `$scope` variables and then using them in PHP, I am using both `ng-model` and `name` field in input tags...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can generate a Office Word Document so easily with a couple of headers and nothing else ...

[This PHP Library would do the trick of the creation of a Word File](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

[Here's a simple example of how to create a Office Word 2007 file using PHPOffice/PHPWord](http://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/general.html#basic-example)
Remember use the correct writer

```
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

Good luck

Comment: But i used the headers for php only version of my project... its just not working here where I am try to output angular scope values... Just these two lines are extra here `$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$array = json_decode($json, true);`